# multiple image upload from frontend in wordpress

Tags: forms, wordpress

I have a CPT "Annonce" which is supposed to have four attached images. Now I building a frontend form to allow users to submit posts with four image upload fields. When I try to submit the form with multiple images, only the last image appears as featured in the dashboard. I see the other images in Media section but not in the post edit page so I can change or delete theme.

I'm using this code in page-post.php:

```
        if ( $_FILES ) {
        $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                $file = array(
                    'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                    'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                    'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                    'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
                );

                $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);

                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
...

<label for="postPhoto1">Photo 1 :</label>
<input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="postPhoto1">

<label for="postPhoto1">Photo 2 :</label>
<input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="postPhoto2">
```

and in functions.php I have this function:

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
  return $attach_id;
}
```

Using this form the images are successfully uploaded but only last image get set as featured image, and I want to show other images in the post edit page too.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can install advanced custom fields plugin,create as many image fields as you want,and then use it in frontend with the method described in documentation.
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-a-front-end-form/

This method is tested and working by me in wordpress 3.4.2, later editions had problems with uploading from frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 < input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment[]" multiple="multiple" >
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code work for you

```
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    $attach_ids=array();
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);

            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file,$post_id);
                array_push($attach_ids , $attach_id);
            }
        }
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_attachment', $attach_ids);
```

html code :

```
        <input multiple type="file" name="upload_attachment[]"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).